# Recover file name from old NTFS partition

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

I have an old NTFS partition from Windows XP (system partition) where I once stored a certain file. I know about where its stored and furthermore guess the file ending. Plus, I don't need the content of the file, the file name is perfectly sufficient.

The reason why I'm asking this, of course, is that this file is deleted. I tried recovery tools but it didn't help. Testdisk comes up with a lot files because it's a system partition and its impossible to read all the names.

It would be great to have a list of the name of as many deleted files as possible because I then could find it with ease. But I don't see a good way to do this with testdisk except for maybe cloning the output, placing a stone on the keyboard to scroll trough all the results and then to come back after a week to proceed.

To you know how I can get such a list? Or a list of as many deleted files that last were in a certain directory?

Edit: I'm currently downloading Ubuntu 12.04 to check out the software mentioned in the comments below since 12.04 is the newest version of Ubuntu with this package. I thought that I had a machine running Ubuntu 12.04 but as it turned out it's Ubuntu 12.10.

Edit 2: I guess that I probably should mention here, too, that the proposed solution in the question this question allegedly is a duplicate of, didn't work. I now tried it and got errors: pastebin.com/JtTnPCD9 But I also got a long list of deleted files, none of which even match the file extension candidates. I also know another part of the file name but it also doesn't occur even once, so I can rule out that the file I'm searching for is in there.

Edit 3: I'm searching for a video. Either the name of the file or its content is okay. I don't need both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover accidentally removed files on NTFS partition](/q/59968)

Comment: @DavidFoerster, no, it's not. I actually ruled this out in my problem description. There is no need for data recovery which I clearly stated. The question you link to only contains a mention of testdisk, another software which doesn't help and a link to another question the answer of which is testdisk. I actually said in my question that I know about testdisk and have used it to try a recovery but it is impractical to use because I virtually had to scroll through about 1 million file names.

Comment: I found a better duplicate, which doesn't even mention Testdisk. Refresh this page in your browser and see the new link in my first comment.

Comment: The duplicates you talk about are the very same question. I'm currently at a very slow internet connection, so I couldn't do it yesterday because I had to wait for the download of Ubuntu 12.04 to finish. I now tried it and got errors: http://pastebin.com/JtTnPCD9 But I also got a long list of deleted files, none of which even match the file extension candidates. I also know another part of the file name but it also doesn't occur even once, so I can rule out that the file I'm searching for is in there.

Comment: Wasn't there a hint for a Windows program to try, yesterday? I have a Windows installation which I could use to try this program. I didn't try this yesterday because I was making a copy of the partition with the deleted file and was waiting for it to end until I would make another copy on a not encrypted medium because I don't want to enter passwords for strong encryption on a Windows pc. However, now the answer with the proposed program is gone.

Comment: What's wrong with browsing the content of the partition with `testdisk` and narrow down the list to just the files present in that folder?

Comment: Testdisk doesn't detect the file, so I hope some other program can.

Comment: When I used Photorec which is part of testdisk, it recovered all my files & all my deleted files. I had saved some text files many times and had to run various grep commands to find which files were the same and then do many compares with last backup to try to recover the changes. You can set photorec to only recover certain files by extension, but since it is scanning entire drive it still takes forever. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Comment: Did you get anything while execute `grep -ia wesom /path/to/file.img` while the file name contains `wesom` (i.e. `my_awesome_video`)?

Comment: Have you considered using the file command to eliminate non matching prospects rather than extensions? It's possible that you eliminated the file you were looking for due to the extension not matching expectations.. Just a thought. You could also try foremost.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use it to search for all video files?

Comment: I don't really know what this command does. How long is the output measured from each end of the string searched? Is it basically what [this script](http://pastebin.com/x6TArgML) does? I get `grep: memory exhausted` as error message.

Comment: I get `grep: memory exhausted` as an error message. Does it mean ram? I'm running it again and am looking out for massive ram usage. It currently "only" uses 1.2 GiB of ram. There is plenty left unused.

Comment: I have no idea why this keeps happening. At some point the used memory rises but the system doesn't swap, the used memory hits the limit of available memory, then `grep` is  killed and the used memory drops. [Here is a screenshot.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9402513/2015-04-09%20System%20runs%20Out%20Of%20Memory%20during%20Execution%20of%20command%20Grep.png)

Comment: @Helio Thank you. I now saved this comment so it doesn't get deleted like the answer naming a possible recovery program.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm about to depart and won't be able to try it again the next weeks. So I give to bounty to the one who helped the most – @kos – even tough I didn't get the file name or its content yet. But I haven't even tried everything he said, yet, so there still is a chance. And I'm glad that downvote was reversed and out of the 3 or 4 votes to close this question (5 required to do so) all but one have been withdrawn.

Comment: @UTF-8 Thanks, let me know if you got any result when you have the chance to test again

Comment: @Helio Yes, go ahead and delete it. I already saved it before I wrote the comment.

Comment: @kos I will. (some more characters so I can send the comment)

Answer (score 5):

If `testdisk` couldn't see the file, that means that the filesystem entry containing the references to it has been overwritten already.

As for any overwritten file, there's no way to recover such overwritten entry (i.e. there's no way to recover the filename).

But **if recovering the file's content is enough**, you can try to use `photorec`, which will read the device block by block looking for known file structure patterns (**also note that per its scope `photorec` will recover any file of the same type of the missing file's type present on the drive**); assuming that your file had a `.ext` extension:

1. Open a `Terminal` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Install `photorec`: `sudo apt-get install testdisk`
3. Run `photorec`: `sudo photorec`
4. Select the drive containing the partition from which the file was deleted and choose `Proceed`
5. Choose `File Opt`
6. Hit <kbd>s</kbd> to untick all the entries in the list. Find the entry containing the `.ext` extension, hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
7. Select the partition from which the file was deleted and choose `Search`
8. Select the partition type and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
9. Navigate to the directory in which you wish to recover the deleted file(s) using <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> and hit <kbd>C</kbd>
10. Wait, this might take a while based on your drive type (HDD/SSD) and on your drive size
11. Browse to the folder in which you chose to recover the file(s) and see if your file was recovered

Comment: Wrong installation command, `photorec` is in the package `testdisk`.

Comment: I tried it and got a number of files in the six-digits back. I then deleted them via search per file extension until I ended up with slightly more than 3'000 files which I then excluded or searched manually. It wasn't there. :(

Comment: I'm searching for a video file, btw. Either content or the file name is okay, I don't need both.

Comment: @UTF-8 Thanks, updated. If you are sure that it wasn't there, then I'm sorry but I don't think that's something else you could try despite trying to use another software to perform the same block-by-block search, but `photorec` is usually good, so I think odds that by switching program you'll be able to recover it are low

Comment: @UTF-8 Have a look at Elder Geek's comment above this one. In fact thinking about it I'm not sure that extensions are recoverable without ambiguity, since for example you can't distinguish a `.conf` file from a `.txt` file. That's probably different for media, since I think that the container can always be recognized, but maybe it's worth a shot

Comment: Are the file names scrapped when a file is deleted? Because I ran a script over an image of the partition and I think I found names of files which I deleted in the output.

Comment: So I should take a look at other video formats, too?

Comment: Here is the script I ran: http://pastebin.com/x6TArgML I basically searched for something in the file name and printed a few characters before it. (I write quick&dirty scripts in PHP.)

Comment: @UTF-8 For example, `Advanced Streaming Format` streams might be contained in `.asf`, `wma` and `wmv` containers. I guess that either `photorec` can match the stream but not the container or those containers are in fact equivalent (and mismatchable), even tough it sounds weird. But otherwise there's no logic reason to merge everything in a single option. Try to run the script (which I haven't checked) over all the extensions grouped under the type of stream that you chose instead of focusing only on the expected extension

Comment: @UTF-8 Can you explain exactly what that `PHP` script does? Looks like you're you parsing the image for filenames. Anyway as said already try checking the other extensions grouped under the same entry ticked for the search in `photorec`

Comment: Yet, it checks fore some part of the file name and then prints out 80 characters ahead of the end of the entered file name snippet up to the end of the given file name snippet. This of course only works if the file names are still there. It doesn't find what I'm searching for, so my question is whether NTFS deletes file names the instance a file is deleted or I just got unlucky because NTFS overrode the particular place where the file name was saved.

Comment: @UTF-8 Probably you had bad luck, since the default behavior is to just remove the entry, anyway I don't know how `NTFS` manages his entries, perhaps it's likely that the most recent deleted entries are prone to be overwritten first. Anyway I'd give a shot to checking the other extensions before giving up